# Clear text from a dynamic edittext box?

Tags: android, types, android-edittext

I have an app that dynamically adds EditText boxes in one method, and I want to use a button to clear those dynamic EditText boxes.

When they were created, I gave them integer IDs and I'm able to access the EditText variable in the activity. So how do I call that dynamic EditText box by its ID number and clear the text?

Comment: Maybe post some code that you have so far and we can go from there.

Comment: if you do yourCreatedEditText.setTag(intId), then you could iterate the touchables of the view you added them to.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save a reference (or list of references) as Activity field? Populate the list and then onClick loop and clear. Doing it by ID is less efficient since you would have to perform a lookup

Answer (score 0):

`((EditText) findViewById(id)).setText("");`

Answer (score 0):

Reset edittext box on click the button

can.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log.setText("");
            pswd.setText("");
        }
    });
```